# Error creating entity Microsoft SQL server IDENTITY_INSERT

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jhipster

I'm using JHipster 4. I've create a simple entity just with a "name" property and when I try to create a entity from UI I get the folowing error. (I'm using Microsoft SQL Server). 
In think the important part of the error is :

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tenant' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Answer (score 1):

## Direct answer appears to be that you just need to configure jhipster to have `identity_insert` on, per this link: https://jhipster.github.io/tips/004_tip_using_ms_sql_server.html

> Adding the identityInsertEnabled="true" is the same as wrapping your Inserts with IDENTITY_INSERT ON and IDENTITY_INSERT OFF which will allow you to insert the project autogenerated identities directly. This is why we are using the MS SQL Server Liquibase for.

---

The error tells you everything you need to know.  You are trying to `insert` a value in to an `identity` column.  This is not allowed, as the column is supposed to be automatically populated unless you explicitly turn it off temporarily.

Documentation on what `identity_insert` is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx

You can turn it off using the command `set identity_insert SchemaName.TableName off` though you had better be very confident you are `insert`ing the correct data.

I would recommend you do some investigation with whoever manages your database as to why that column is an `identity` column and whether or not you should be `insert`ing into it at all.

---

Assume a table:

```
create table test(ID   int identity(1,1)
                 ,Name nvarchar(100)
                 )
```

ALL of these `insert` statements will throw an error:

```
insert into test(ID,Name)
select ID
      ,Name
from OtherTable

insert into test(ID,Name)
select null as ID
      ,'TestName' as Name

insert into test(ID,Name)
values(99
      ,'Name'
      )
```

Whereas these will work, automatically generating a new, unique value for the `ID` column:

```
insert into test(Name)
select Name
from OtherTable

insert into test(Name)
select 'TestName' as Name

insert into test(Name)
values('Name')
```

In short, you need to `insert` *nothing* into the `identity` column.  Not a blank string, not a `null` value, but absolutely nothing at all.

Comment: Yes, I understand but I'm not really setting value to 'id' column. If a make debug , the value of 'id' is null. This is a JHipster generated code wihout any modification for me.

Comment: @Víctor  It sounds like you are still trying to explicitly `insert` a `null` value.  This also violates the `identity_insert`.  I'll edit my answer with some more info/examples.

Comment: You are right, but I'm not writing any code because is JHipster (a generator of code "who" is implementing the code for me. Finally, I discover that JHipster is generating the id of the entity like this :  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator"). That is not correct because the column of the table generated has "IDENTITY", so I've modified the bean like this    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY). I think this is a bug of JHipster 4 when is working with SQL Server. Thanks!!

Comment: @Víctor  I have edited my answer to include what I think is a relevant link for you to get your `jhipster` entities working.